# How do I change the color of the label outside of the didSelectRowAtIndexPath function?

Tags: ios, swift

I can currently click on multiple rows and change the color of the labels, and go to the next view controller but when I come back to the table view I print the selectrowatindexpath in the view will appear and I get the correct values, but the labels are not colored in. Selected means that the label is white, but the label is not even though it prints the selected values. How do I fix this?

```
var selected = ["dog", "cat", "bat"]
var animal = [String]() //selected data

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: selectcell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! selectcell
    cell.subjecters.text = selected[indexPath.row]
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

    if(animal != []){
        for(var i = 0; i < selected.count; i++){
            for(var x = 0; x < animal.count; x++){
                if(selected[i] == animal[x]){
                    var rowtoselect = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0)
                    self.table.selectRowAtIndexPath(rowtoselect, animated: true, scrollPosition: .None)


                    cell.subject.textColor = UIColorFromRGB("f07763")

                }
            }

        }
    }


    return cell
}



     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let currentCell = table.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! selectcell
    currentCell.subject.textColor = UIColorFromRGB("ffffff")
    currentCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    self.selected.append(currentCell.subjecter.text!) 
}
```

Comment: Rather than updating the view (the table view cell) update the model (the data source array) and then reload the view.

Comment: when you are return back **cellForRowAtIndexPath** is called so put your code in that method

Comment: In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you select a row which calls `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` which calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath` which ... .??? That's pretty expensive and ineffective.

Comment: essentially they first enter the view the table view will have dog cat bat, say they select cat and bat. Those labels turn white while dog stays black. They go to the next view, but decide to come back to the table view. Currently I can get back what they previously selected, cat and bat, but they are not highlights white. That's what I am stuck on. @vadian

Answer (score 0):

you're updating the labels in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` func, but that's only called when you make the selection.

when you return to the view, the cells are updated through `cellForRowAtIndexPath` - so change the colour there

Answer (score 0):

Extend your model - the animal array - to be a class with properties `name` and `selected`. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` set the color depending on the `selected` property and remove `selectRow....` After a row is selected get the model item for that row, set `selected` to `true` and reload the table view. That's practical MVC.

```
class Animal {

  let name : String
  var selected = false

  init(name : String) {
    self.name = name
  }
}



class ViewController : UITableViewController {

  var animals = [Animal]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    animals = [Animal(name: "dog"), Animal(name: "cat"), Animal(name: "bat")]
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return animals.count
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: selectcell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! selectcell
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

    let animal = animals[indexPath.row]
    cell.subjecters.text = animal.name
    cell.subject.textColor = animal.selected ?  UIColorFromRGB("ffffff") : UIColorFromRGB("f07763")
    return cell
  }

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let animal = animals[indexPath.row]
    animal.selected = true
    tableView.reloadData()
  }

}
```

Comment: When I click on a cell nothing happens.

Comment: Would I return animals.count in the numberofrows function?

Comment: Cat keeps repeating, I am getting 12 rows with cat in them